# ESP32 server send file from sd card to ftpserver

Tags: ftp, esp32, sd-card

I am working in a project where I have esp32 Devkit v1(server) with SD card module, I want to send file from SD to ftp server through esp32.

my files get tranferred to ftp but it can't open. it shows 0kb.

```
/*
CS   5
SCK  18
MOSI 23
MISO 19
VCC  VIN
GND  GND
*/

#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include "ESP32FtpServer.h"
#include "SD.h"
const char* ssid = "";
const char* password = "";


FtpServer ftpSrv; 

void setup(void){
  Serial.begin(115200);


  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("");
  
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

 
 
  if (SD.begin()) {
      Serial.println("SD opened!");
      ftpSrv.begin("esp32","esp32"); 
(default 21, 50009 for PASV)
  }    
}

void loop(void){
  
      ftpSrv.handleFTP();
     }
```